# Securing an SFTP server

Tags: encryption, ssh, key-exchange, sftp

I have been asked to secure an SFTP service and running a scan using

```
nmap.exe --script ssh2-enum-algos <host> -p 22
```

returns the following:

```
22/tcp open  ssh
| ssh2-enum-algos:
|   kex_algorithms: (3)
|       diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
|       diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
|       diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
|   server_host_key_algorithms: (2)
|       ssh-dss
|       ssh-rsa
|   encryption_algorithms: (5)
|       aes128-ctr
|       3des-cbc
|       blowfish-cbc
|       arcfour128
|       arcfour
|   mac_algorithms: (7)
|       hmac-md5
|       hmac-sha1
|       hmac-md5-96
|       hmac-sha1-96
|       hmac-sha256
|       hmac-sha2-256
|       hmac-sha256@ssh.com
|   compression_algorithms: (2)
|       none
|_      zlib
```

Does anyone know of any reason why I shouldn't configure it as follows:

```
22/tcp open  ssh
| ssh2-enum-algos:
|   kex_algorithms: (1)
|       diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
|   server_host_key_algorithms: (1)
|       ssh-rsa
|   encryption_algorithms: (5)
|       aes128-ctr
|   mac_algorithms: (7)
|       hmac-sha2-256
|       hmac-sha256@ssh.com
|   compression_algorithms: (2)
|       none
|_      zlib
```

I am expecting someone to point out that some of the above components may be needed for legacy applications or older clients but I don't have enough experience to know which :)

By the way, the SSH connection is managed by the SFTP software ( decompiling the java code revealed it was using [Maverick](https://javassh.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/210075426) ) and doesn't rely on OpenSSH.

Comment: Exactly. Older clients may rely on older, less secure algorithms. I also don't think you would need those. I think the best you can do is to test it in a few common clients. If it works with less crypto options, it's fine.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it comes down to testing. I just wasn't sure whether reducing kex_algorithms, for example, down to 1 would be a bad practice.

Comment: Remove zlib compression, maybe. There are attacks that use compression, I don't know if they're applicable in sftp context. Otherwise I don't see a problem, it's not like this is ssh you use to administer the server - if you can't connect you're not locked out and can relax the settings. If the server supports elliptic curve crypto, ecdh and ed25519 keys are better than your config.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the users you expect to connect to your server. If you are in control of the clients (you can verify which algorithms do they support and/or update them), your proposed list is security very reasonable (quite much all you excluded have some security weakness).

If you do not have control of the clients, you can still log the supported list of algorithms for some time and verify you will not cut out most of the clients. These days is no reason why an up-to-date client should not support your proposed algorithms so issuing some message "Please, update your client" would make sense.

The backward compatibility is important mostly for the clients, because there are ancient devices running SSH server unable to update their software. But this should not be a problem for SSH clients.